# magento menu IE bug

Tags: internet-explorer, magento, menu

i'm using magento and the standard topmenu (with 1 sublevel). the problem is, that in IE < 10 the submenu is flickering on hover and then disappears. how to fix this problem? hopefully just with css.

the html:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li  class="level0 nav-1 first level-top parent">
       <a href="..."  class="level-top" ><span>Level0</span></a>
           <ul class="level0">
               <li  class="level1 nav-1-1 first">
                    <a href="..." ><span>Level1</span></a>
               </li>
           </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the css:

```
#nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 56px;
    background: #5b4c43;
}

#nav ul,#nav div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 540px;
    top: 56px;
    left: -10000px;
    background: #f2f2ed;
    background-color: #f2f2ed;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    padding: 35px;
}

#nav div ul {
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    border: none;
}

/* All Levels */
#nav li {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li.over {
    z-index: 998;
}

/* 1st Level */
#nav li {
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 0;
}

#nav li:hover,#nav li.active {
    background: #40352f;
    border-left: 1px solid #4e4e4e;
}

#nav ul li.level1 {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b3a791;
    width: 240px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    color: #39312b;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

/* Show menu */
#nav li ul.shown-sub,#nav li div.shown-sub {
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

#nav li .shown-sub ul.shown-sub,#nav li .shown-sub li div.shown-sub {
    left: 100px;
}
```

the js:
on hover it adds the class to the ul and li "over" and "shown-sub"